# Maximum value question of three $xyz+xy+yz+zx$.

Tags: maximum-principle

[image]

I have tried am-gm inequality,i am getting that $xyz$ is greater than $36.9$.

I tried hit and trial,but it is of no use also.

Could anyone give a definite process?

Comment: As pointed out by anant, please clarify if your domain is non negative integers, or non-negative reals. The approaches are different.

Comment: In case you're interested, there's another way of solving this if the numbers are positive reals: just use the inequalities $$xyz\le \left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^3$$
$$xy+yz+zx\le \frac{(x+y+z)^2}{3}$$
Which, again, shows that the maximum is reached when $x=y=z$ given that they are positive reals. But this doesn't fully satisfy the conditions, just like Calvin's answer doesn't either.

Comment: Can u say how u get the second inequality.

Comment: @user146181 You should've written '@mathh' so that I can see that you're asking me a question (on my notifications). You're lucky I just went through this question again and saw your comment. First of all, talking about the inequality, prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$ by getting that $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\ge 0$ after multiplying both sides by $2$. After you've proved it, add $2(ab+bc+cd)$ to both sides of the inequality and use factorization... I'm sure you can finish the proof.

Comment: @user146181 Is it clear now?

Comment: @mathh i got that a2+b2+c2≥ab+bc+ca.

Comment: As I said in the comment, add $2(ab+bc+ca)$ to both sides of the inequality. You now have $$a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)=(a+b+c)^2\ge 3(ab+bc+ca)$$

Comment: @mathh Thanks,for spending your precious time.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $x+1+y+1+z+1=13$

Bound $(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)$ from above using AM-GM.

Hence maximum is $(13/3)^3-11$ and occurs when $x=y=z$.

Comment: very nice Calvin!

Comment: But we can't have integer $x = y = z$ right?

Comment: @anant considering that OP used decimals in his answer, I believe that he wants a domain of real numbers. If it was integers, there are just a few cases to check

Comment: Okay. For integers, how would we approach the problem if $x + y + z$ was large (say 2000)?

Comment: @anant: For integers, the integers nearest to the value satisfying ${x+y+z=2000}$ when ${x=y=z}$ will yield the greatest value to the equation. For ${2000}$ it will be ${666,667,667}$ for ${x,y,z}$. :)

Comment: Yes,i got it but can u inform me how u prepared exactly (x+1)(y+1)(z+1).

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer has so many upvotes given that it doesn't take into account the fact that $x,y,z$ are non-negative integers.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Yes,i got it but can u inform me how u prepared exactly (x+1)(y+1)(z+1).

Comment: @mathh See my clarification attempt (first comment on the problem). I worked over the positive reals as the OP gave a decimal value, which indicated to me that he was thinking of it as real values. Had his answer been an integer, I would have done a case argument.

Comment: @user146181 Experience. That looked like a good factorization to consider, mathh's solution in comments works too.

Answer (score 1):

$xyz+xy+yz+zx=xyz~\bigg(1+\dfrac1x+\dfrac1y+\dfrac1z\bigg)$, but the [harmonic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) of the three variables is $H=\dfrac3{\dfrac1x+\dfrac1y+\dfrac1z}\iff\dfrac1x+\dfrac1y+\dfrac1z=\dfrac3H$ . At the same time, $A>G>H$, with $A=\dfrac{10}3$ and

$G=\sqrt[3]{xyz}~=>$ we are left with maximizing $G^3\bigg(1+\dfrac3H\bigg)\geqslant G^3\bigg(1+\dfrac3G\bigg)$, which lower bound peaks for $G_\text{max}=A=\dfrac{10}3$ , which only happens when $x=y=z$. Since the three variables are integers, the solutions obtained by rounding are $3,3$, and $4$, for which we have a maximum of $69$, which is just shy of the global maximum $\dfrac{1900}{3^3}\approx70.37$, obtained for $x=y=z=3\dfrac13\cdot$ QED.